# connect speech to text API to Java script

Tags: javascript, api, websphere, ibm-watson

I am trying to convert Arabic speech to text and one of the APIs I want to use is IBM Watson .. Anyone have an idea of how to connect its API to Java script or a web app?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Habiba, have you seen the [Watson javascript-sdk for speech](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk)? Also check out the [API reference for Node](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=node).